# SetEnvIf doesnt work from htaccess

Tags: php, apache-2.4, http, cgi

I'm trying to overcome the infamous missing Auth header problem with Apache, PHP and CGI.

If I set this in a virtual host, I can successfully read the Bearer token from the Authorization header.

SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

However, I'd like to set it at an application level in my .htaccess file. Despite the web directory having AllowOverride All set, this directive in my .htaccess file doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" - the variable doesn't appear? You get an error? Something else? What did you check? Please clarify.

Comment: The variable doesn't exist in PHP, same as if I had no directive at all.